# Android: best way(9 patch or gradient shape in xml) to draw two gradients(see screenshot)

Tags: android, gradient

[image: sample]

I need to add background to a textview, the background has two parts: top half is a gradent from color A to B, bottom part is a gradient from color C to D and B does not equal to C, it is actually a semi-transparent shadow, I intentionally put an orange layer underneath it to make it clear to see.

I am looking for the best way to do it, using shape/gradient only allows me setting startColor, centerColor and endColor but I need for color points. Using 9 patch is a bit complicated. Or can I merge two gradients together so each has two colors and together give me four colors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9 patch seems the simplest way to achieve what you want. And I believe, it would generate less computations to display your image.

9 patch is not so complicated, even easy. Did you try the [android 9 patch tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. But I still do not know, do I need to create three versions for hdpi, mdpi and ldpi? I only have one version of artwork. I put it in hdpi folder only, the result looks fine in hi res screen, but it is not scaled(ie, the bar takes nearly half screen) in low res screen.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I am not very familliar yet with the different resolutions in android.

Comment: 9patches just allow you to define particular areas of your image that you wish you stretch (and not stretch). How are you supposed to 9patch a gradient? I don't think it is really suitable in this case (or rather, it is no better than default image stretching).